# Как вернуть ссылкам функционал после return false?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такая структура:

```
<li class="flash">
    <div class="diler-item">
        <div class="diler-close"></div>
           <div class="diler-row">
                <h4>Заголовок</h4>
                <p>Текст</p>
                <a href="http://сайт.ру">Ссылка на сайт</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

И ей сделан вот такой код js.

```
$(function(){
    var titles = $('.flash'),
        close = $('.diler-close');


    titles.on('click',function(e){

        $(this).prevAll('.flash').removeClass('open');
        $(this).nextAll('.flash').removeClass('open');
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }).children().click(function(e) {
        return false;
    });

    close.on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open');
    });

});
```

Здесь по нажатию на .flash всплывает его дочерний элемент .diler-item с информацией. Закрываются другие похожие окна. Сделано по принципу аккордеона.
Return false для .children был добавлен, чтобы клик по .diler-item не закрывал это окно.

Все работало так, как надо, пока во всплывающем окне не была добавлена ссылка - клик по ней не срабатывает.

- Пробовал как-то исключить ее из .children - не получилось;
- без return false работает ссылка, но срабатывает клик по нажатию на самом .diler-item (всплывающем окне) и его элементах;

Пример на jsfiddle: [Здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/995038/)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как доработать код, чтобы и ссылки работали и весь этот вроде не сложный функционал оставался...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из кода в ответе не переходит по ссылке. Поэтому вот: https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/ZVbYNQ

```js
$(function(){
  var contents = $('.diler-item'),
   titles = $('.flash'),
   close = $('.diler-close');


   titles.on('click',function(e){
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('flash')) {
         $(this).prevAll('.flash').removeClass('open');
         $(this).nextAll('.flash').removeClass('open');
         $(this).toggleClass('open');
         }
     })
  close.on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open');
  });

 });
```

```css
body {
  background: #1e202c;
}
.diler-map .container {
  padding: 150px 150px; }
  .diler-map .container h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin: 0 0 60px; }
  .diler-map .container .map {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;}
    .diler-map .container .map img {
      width: 100%; }
    .diler-map .container .map .dilers {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none; }
      .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        z-index: 5;
        background: #fff;}
        .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash:nth-child(2) {
          top: 200px;
        }
        .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash:nth-child(3) {
          top: 400px;
        }
        .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash:before {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          margin: -2.5px 0 0 -2.5px;
          width: 5px;
          height: 5px;
          content: "";
          -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
          border-radius: 100%;
          -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
          -o-transition: all .3s ease;
          transition: all .3s ease;}
        .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item {
          position: absolute;
          left: 100%;
          top: 50%;
          margin: -150px 0 0 30px;
          background: #000;
          background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(110, 117, 135, 0.5)), color-stop(81%, rgba(30, 32, 44, 0.9)));
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110, 117, 135, 0.5) 0%, rgba(30, 32, 44, 0.9) 81%);
          background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110, 117, 135, 0.5) 0%, rgba(30, 32, 44, 0.9) 81%);
          background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(110, 117, 135, 0.5) 0%, rgba(30, 32, 44, 0.9) 81%);
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6e7587', endColorstr='#1e202c', GradientType=0 );
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          padding: 20px;
          width: 300px;
          height: 300px;
          overflow-y: auto;
          cursor: initial;
          opacity: 0;
          visibility: hidden;
          -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
          -ms-transform: translateY(40px);
          transform: translateY(40px);
          -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
          -o-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
          transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
          z-index: 10; }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item h3 {
            margin: 0 0 15px;
            font-family: "PobedaRegular", "Arial", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
            font-size: 2em;
            font-weight: normal; }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-row h4 {
            margin: 20px 0 15px;
            font-weight: 600; }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-row p {
            margin: 10px 0; }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-row a {
            color: #fff; }
            .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-row a.sertificate:before {
              content: "";
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 2px;
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #fff;
              box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #fff;
              -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
              -ms-transform: translateY(3px);
              transform: translateY(3px);
              -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
              -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
              transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1); }
            .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-row a.sertificate:hover:before {
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #fff;
              box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #fff;
              -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
              -ms-transform: translateY(0);
              transform: translateY(0); }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-close {
            position: absolute;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            top: 30px;
            right: 10px;
            cursor: pointer; }
            .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-close svg {
              fill: #dedede;
              -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
              -o-transition: all .3s ease;
              transition: all .3s ease; }
              .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item .diler-close svg:hover {
                fill: #fff; }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item.several .diler-row {
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); }
            .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash .diler-item.several .diler-row:last-child {
              border-bottom: none; }
        .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash.open {
          z-index: 12; }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash.open:before {
            background-color: #fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px #bac2d6;
            box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px #bac2d6; }
          .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash.open .diler-item {
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            -ms-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0); }
        .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash ::-webkit-scrollbar {
          background: rgba(110, 117, 135, 0.5);
          width: 5px; }
        .diler-map .container .map .dilers .flash ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
          background: #6e7587; }
  .diler-map .container .main-btn.diler-btn {
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 65px;
    line-height: 65px;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 60px auto 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="diler-map">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="map">
    <ul class="dilers">
     <li class="flash">
      <div class="diler-item">
       <div class="diler-close">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M13 12l5-5-1-1-5 5-5-5-1 1 5 5-5 5 1 1 5-5 5 5 1-1z"></path></svg>
       </div>
       <div class="diler-row">
        <h4>Заголовок</h4>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Перейти на сайт</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="flash">
      <div class="diler-item">
       <div class="diler-close">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M13 12l5-5-1-1-5 5-5-5-1 1 5 5-5 5 1 1 5-5 5 5 1-1z"></path></svg>
       </div>
       <div class="diler-row">
        <h4>Заголовок</h4>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Перейти на сайт</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="flash">
      <div class="diler-item">
       <div class="diler-close">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M13 12l5-5-1-1-5 5-5-5-1 1 5 5-5 5 1 1 5-5 5 5 1-1z"></path></svg>
       </div>
       <div class="diler-row">
        <h4>Заголовок</h4>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Перейти на сайт</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Да нет, тут дело не в заголовке - на клик по .flash надо добавление класса - контент внутри не должен взаимодействовать, выполнять стандартные функции (кроме .close). Вас смутила переменная title - я извиняюсь за это.

Comment: А можете добавить чуть больше в пример. Чтоб было два элемента которые открываются/закрываются?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/995038/ - собрал на скорую руку живой пример того, что работает на сайте. JS с тем, что предложил YD1m

Comment: @Sepika, Поправил свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сработало)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(function(){
    var titles = $('.flash'),
    close = $('.diler-close');

    $(function(){
        var contents = $('.diler-item'),
        titles = $('.flash'),
        close = $('.diler-close');

        titles.on('click',function(e){
            $(this).prevAll('.flash').removeClass('open');
            $(this).nextAll('.flash').removeClass('open');
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        }).find('*:not(svg)').click(function(e) {           
            if(!$(this).is('a')) {
                return false;
            } else {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }           
        });

        close.on('click',function(){    
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open');
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/995130/)

Comment: Попробовал, но, увы... Клик по ссылке все так же не срабатывает(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/995038/ - собрал свой пример с вашим кодом

Comment: @Sepika вот так у меня получилось. Смотрите исправленный вариант.

Comment: Да, так тоже работает. Вариант даже чуть компактней, предложенный @Lukas. Спасибо!